# Using Excel formula in PHP. Use ^ symbol

Tags: php

how do i calculate this in php

```
(1-(1+(0.004936230552))^-((48)))
```

This is a formula in google excel sheet and i can't produce the same result in php.
The actual answer is **0.2105005887**
But when i use this in php i get this answer **5.2121761747624E+110**

i am using pow function of php
This is my code

```
echo pow(1-(1+(0.004936230552)),-((48)));
```

Thank you.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with WordPress. Try [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Comment: Oops. My mistake.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the answer you are looking for:

```
echo 1 - pow( (1+(0.004936230552)), (-48) );
```

That will output 0.21050058867618.

It's an order of operations issue; the spreadsheet version of the formula is subtracting from 1 last, while the PHP in the question is subtracting from 1 earlier.